# How to test thermal printer print preview in IOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, thermal-printer

I want to display thermal print preview before printing, How can I do this?

Is there any solution to test online from web URL Or using webview or any other method, Please suggest.

Comment: Have you checked this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206207/printing-the-view-in-ios-with-swift

Comment: I have tested this, it's for normal print like A4 size, I want to test thermal printer preview.

Comment: please check this https://github.com/tovganesh/bleprinter-ios